# Winmerge Ignored lines -how to change the colour from yellow to white (not highlighted/ignored)

Tags: winmerge

I want to ignore comment lines beginning with # and I don't want these lines to be highlighted in light yellow (default colour)

Answer (score 0):

Two steps

a) I want to ignore comments. In my case lines beginning with #
Add a new line filter
Tools, Filters, Line Filters
New Regular Expression ^#

This ignores any line beginning with a #

b) I do not want Winmerge to highlight this line in light yellow
(when there are differences in the comments)

Edit, Options, Colors, Differences
Focus on row Ignored Differences, change the Background and Deleted to White
(i.e. double click on the colour and then change it to white)

I'm a Winmerge newbie so there may be better ways of doing this.